# added library to my custom library could not be found

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I built an android library and added a library to it for a custom rating bar. used it in my library and everything was ok until i added my library to an empty app for test. then I get this error while trying to build the app.

...
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not find com.github.giswangsj:AndRatingBar:1.0.5.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/giswangsj/AndRatingBar/1.0.5/AndRatingBar-1.0.5.pom
> - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/giswangsj/AndRatingBar/1.0.5/AndRatingBar-1.0.5.pom
> - https://maven.google.com/com/github/giswangsj/AndRatingBar/1.0.5/AndRatingBar-1.0.5.pom
> - http://xxx.xxx1.xxxx.xxx:xxxxx/artifactory/libs-release-local/com/github/giswangsj/AndRatingBar/1.0.5/AndRatingBar-1.0.5.pom
> Required by:
> project :app > xxx.xxx.xxxdk:xxx:1.0.6
> ...

It could not find the rate bar library I added to my library.

here is how I added my library to the app

root gradle file

repositories{
...
maven { url "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx/artifactory/libs-release-local" }
...
}

http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx/artifactory is where I stored my library

app build.gradle file

dependencies {
...
implementation 'xxx.xxxx.xxxx:xxxxx:1.0.6'
...
}

Comment: is the version your app is looking for is the same version of the rating library your library was able to use correctly?

Comment: @dinkar_kumar what do you mean by version my app is looking for? i just implemented my library in the app. I'm not looking for rating library in the app just in my library

Comment: I get it, I am saying 1.0.5 is the version of rating you included in your library code?

Comment: @dinkar_kumar yes

Comment: and how are you including your library to your app ?

Comment: @dinkar_kumar i will edit my question to include app Gradle files

Comment: @dinkar_kumar sorry for taking so long. i updated the question. hope it would be clear.

Comment: I would recommend trying one thing add the AndRatingBar dependency in your app and try once and let me know, I think it will work

Comment: @MahdiTaheri The aar file cannot contain the nested dependencies or transitive dependencies. You will have to include them in your app module gradle. Check this stackoverflow answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37066280/create-a-library-with-dependencies-in-android

Comment: thanks for your helps

Comment: @dinkar_kumar i be really grateful if you edit your answer and change the IP for security reasons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add AndRatingBar dependency in your app as well, That will fix the issue as your repository (http://xxxx.xx:xxxxx/artifactory) is not having AndRatingBar hosted to resolve and also the AndRatingBar is neither on google maven server or apache maven server but jitpack server.
If you would have hosted your library on maven server with pom defining the AndRatingBar then you would have not needed to add the dependency in app separately.